# How to get consolidated output table in single line

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created sample database

```sql
create table items (Order_date date, frame char(2) , group_name varchar(50) , order_qty int(4) , receive_qty int(4));

insert into items(Order_date , frame , group_name , order_qty ,receive_qty) values 
("2021-3-10" , "am" , "books" , 4280 , 4000), 
("2021-3-12" , "pm" , "notebooks" , 3259 , 3100), 
("2021-3-14" , "pm" , "erasers" , 2828 , 2500), 
("2021-3-15" , "am" , "books" , 3147 , 3088), 
("2021-3-16" , "pm" , "notebooks" , 2897 , 2700), 
("2021-3-19" , "am" , "notebooks" , 4793 , 3030), 
("2021-3-21" , "pm" , "erasers" , 3317 , 3100);
```

#Query to get Fill Rate

```
select group_name , (sum(receive_qty)/sum(order_qty)*100) as Fill_Rate 
from items 
group by group_name;
```

#Query to get Fill Rate when frame is AM

```
select group_name , (sum(receive_qty)/sum(order_qty)*100) as AM_Fill_Rate 
from items 
where frame = "am" 
group by group_name;
```

#Query to get Fill Rate post 16 mar 2021

```
select group_name , (sum(receive_qty)/sum(order_qty)*100) as Fill_Rate_post_16Mar 
from items 
where Order_date >= "2021-03-16" 
group by group_name;
```

**How can I get Fill_Rate , AM_Fill_Rate and Fill_Rate_post_16Mar in single table in single run??
since i can get all 3 by individually running above 3 queries , 3 times**

Please suggest !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
select group_name , 
       (sum(receive_qty)/sum(order_qty)*100) as Fill_Rate ,
       (sum(case when frame = "am" then receive_qty else 0 end)/sum(case when frame = "am" then order_qty else 0 end)*100) as AM_Fill_Rate 
       (sum(case when Order_date >= "2021-03-16" then receive_qty else 0 end)/sum(case when Order_date >= "2021-03-16" then order_qty else 0 end)*100) as Fill_Rate_post_16Mar 
from items 
group by group_name;
```